# UITableViewCell very slow response on select

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a simple UITableViewController with basic cell.
didSelectRowAtIndexPath do simple job - just make UIAlertView and show it.

The problem is when I tap on a row sometimes I see alert immediately, sometimes after few seconds (up to 10 seconds).

The code is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("row clicked at index \(indexPath.row)")
    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Test", message: "Test message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Done")
    alert.show()
    NSLog("alert showed")
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}
```

In log I see

```
2015-08-06 20:51:54.591 experimental[10323:8602172] row clicked at index 2
2015-08-06 20:51:54.595 experimental[10323:8602172] alert showed
2015-08-06 20:52:00.901 experimental[10323:8602172] row clicked at index 3
2015-08-06 20:52:00.905 experimental[10323:8602172] alert showed
```

but actually alert not shows on the screen.

Any suggestions or pointings where to find a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: You should check with instruments. This code seems fine.

Comment: Actually UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController.

Comment: Maybe the problem with xCode Version 6.4 (6E35b) but I have same problem on real device, not only in simulator

Comment: Thanks, stosha, but problem not in UIAlertView. Any code have sam effect.

Answer (score 27):

The solution is very weird

replacing

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

with

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default
```

completely solve the problem. After that **every** click on row will show result immediately.

Comment: Really weird. I use UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue, and has the same issue.  Changing to UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default works for me.

Comment: That's strange! This works for me as well, thanks mate. Any idea? what do we need to do if have to get rid of the selection style.

Comment: this is ridiculous. Anyone knows why?

Comment: OMG! I went crazy because of this... I had a custom transition between 2 view controllers and I thought that my code was the blame for the slow transition. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

put it in DispatchQueue.main.async function.

`DispatchQueue.main.async{`

`let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Test", message: "Test message",` `delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Done")`
    `alert.show()`
    `NSLog("alert showed")`
`}`

and `replace cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` to 
`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default`

Answer (score 3):

If you want `selectionStyle` to be None, you should add the `alertView` method to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{...});`
or set the `selectionStyle` to Default.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, definitely a bug. In my case it was adding an extra 150ms before loading the view.

I had a custom table cell with

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

changing it to

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default
```

fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0):

i found that use gesture is better than didselect delegate if there is image on the cell

so

```
iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];

tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[iv addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to have selection style `.none` because I use customized cells. Therefore I have to work with `didHighlightRowAt` and `didUnhighlightRowAt`. When you're using `.default` you cannot handle these events.

For me `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
delaysContentTouches = false
```